# Whats the correct way to use Mysql GREATEST() function for a column

Tags: mysql

I have gone through a bunch of SO questions for the correct way to use the mySQL's  `GREATEST()`function but none of them show how to use it with a column.
[Official Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) gives for a list of manually entered list.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632881/how-to-get-the-greatest-of-two-columns-values-in-mysql/1632940#1632940) is about two values only.

I was also unable to get my answer in [A SO Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=greatest+mysql+%5Bmysql%5D).

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually looking for the [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function. You would use it like so:

```
SELECT foo, MAX(bar) FROM baz GROUP BY foo
```

Comment: `SELECT foo, MAX(bar) FROM baz GROUP BY foo LIMIT 1` this is it!
Thanks a bunch. My God!! I was moving in the wrong direction all that time!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `greatest()` function takes two or more arguments and returns the largest value:

```
select greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4) as BiggestCol
from . . .
```

If you want the largest value in a column, then you want the `max()` function:

```
select max(col1) as BiggestValueInCol1
```

Comment: I also like your explanation of the `GREATEST` function. Sorry mate I can only accept one as my answer. :) Regards,